# ILNumeric InArray parameters get disposed after first use

Tags: c#, ilnumerics

I found the InArray parameters of my function will be disposed after the first use. For example:

```
        static ILArray<double> UpdateU(
        ILInArray<double> sigmaK, ILInArray<double> uK, ILInArray<double> vK,
        ILInArray<double> t, ILOutArray<double> outU, ILOutArray<double> outV)
    {
        var q = t.Size[0];
        var m = uK.Size[0];
        var k = uK.Size[1];
        var n = vK.Size[0];

        ILArray<double> hBottom = multiply(t, vK);
        ILArray<double> h = zeros(k + q, k);
        h["0:" + (k - 1), full] = sigmaK[full, full];
        h[k + ":end", full] = hBottom[full, full];

        ILArray<double> uH = empty();
        ILArray<double> vH = empty();
        ILArray<double> sigmaH = svd(h, uH, vH);

        ILArray<double> broadenUK = zeros(m + q, k + q);
        broadenUK["0:" + (m - 1), "0:" + (k - 1)] = uK[full, full];
        broadenUK[m + ":end", k + ":end"] = eye(q, q)[full, full];

        outU.a = multiply(broadenUK, uH);
        outV.a = multiply(vK, vH);

        return sigmaH;
    }
```

Variables t and vK are disposed after the line

```
ILArray<double> hBottom = multiply(t, vK);
```

So is it because my code missing something? Thanks!

Update: If I change the parameter declaration of t and vK from `ILInArray` to `ILArray` they will be preserved fine. But from what I read in the document, the former type is actually the preferred one.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation suggests using ILSCope.Enter with the input arrays. 
This makes sure that the input arrays will be alive till the end of using block and gets disposed right after.

Add the following to the beginning of your function definition

using ILScope.Enter(sigmak, uk, vk, t)

{

// function body here

}